# Custom XmlSerializer only adds namespaces in WebApi

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

We're trying to remove all namespacing from our XML API responses. We're using a custom `BufferedMediaTypeFormatter` that looks like:

```cs
namespace HeyWorld.MediaTypeFormatters
{
    public class SectionMediaTypeFormatter : BufferedMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
        {
            return typeof(SectionResponse) == type;
        }

        public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
        {
            return typeof(SectionResponse) == type;
        }

        public override void WriteToStream(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
        {
            var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };

            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(writeStream, xmlWriterSettings))
            {
                var namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value, namespaces);
            }
        }

        public override object ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
            return serializer.Deserialize(readStream);
        }
    }
}
```

As we understand it (from answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6297387/418586)), that `namespaces.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);` should remove all namespaces from any serialized XML. In unit tests, that's exactly what it does:

```cs
[Test]
public void ShouldntDoNamespaces(){
     var sectionResponse = new SectionResponse("yes!");
     var sectionMediaTypeFormatter = new SectionMediaTypeFormatter();

     using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
     {
         sectionMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(typeof(T), sectionResponse, memoryStream, null);

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
            {
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                Assert.That(reader.ReadToEnd(), Is.EqualTo(
                    '<Section attribute="yes!"></Section>'
                );
            }
        }
}
```

However in the deployed application, it adds default namespaces!

```
GET /Section/21

<Section 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    attribute="yes!"></Section>
```

Maybe it's something configured in our Global.asax?:

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new SectionMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Any help getting rid of those would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to add the supported media types:

```
public class SectionMediaTypeFormatter : BufferedMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public SectionMediaTypeFormatter()
    {
        this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml"));
        this.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml"));
    }
```

Also I see that you want to still keep the default xml formatter...so you want this custom formatter to only apply to `SectionResponse` type and for all other types the default xml formatter should apply...is it?

Comment: Yeah, we're trying to bring things over slowly. But the media types were spot on.